# Aida Web install complains about missing "SecureHashAlgorithm"

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

(Hi, Smalltalk newbie here; I play around with Pharo from time to time, and thought I'd try out one of the web frameworks)

I installed *Aida Web* and when I try to load the Swazoo Server I get an exception somewhere in the `WebSecurityManager` class, which complains about the `SecureHashAlgorithm` class being unavailable.

Some Googling led to a suggestion that it might exist in the `System-Digital Signatures` package, but I couldn't find this within the Monticello browser.

Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aida hasn't been maintaining compatibility with Pharo (or the other way around, depending on your point of view). `SecureHashAlgorithm` is called `SHA1` in Pharo, but works largely the same. I suspect that this won't be the only problem that you're going to run into.

If you want to try anyway, you can make loading work by creating a copy of the the class `SHA1` and name it `SecureHashAlgorithm`. To create a copy, right click on the class name in a class browser and select "copy", then provide the new name.

For completeness: the predominantly used web framework with Pharo is (probably) [Seaside](http://seaside.st) (there are others too which I don't know though).

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility, an alternative would be to use Grease. That is what Seaside uses, and it supports this:

```
GRPlatform current secureHashFor: aString
```

That is of course defined as

```
GRPharoPlatform>>secureHashFor: aString
    ^ SHA1 new hashMessage: aString
```